# React form post as jSONP with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, axios

I'm  currently migrating some of my components from jQuery to React but now I need to POST a form as jSONP.

Normally I did this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: '/files/json/save.json.php',
      data: "id=" + createUpdateId + "&type=" + type,
      complete: function(data){
        // Some logic
      }
    });
```

But now I'm using Axios for fetching data but I can't figure out how to use a callback like I did with jQuery Ajax.

I tried a few things like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp and https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-jsonp but I couldn't get it working.

Any thoughts on this?